# REMOTE ACCESS FROM HOME TO OFFICE

Tags: vpn

How to connect remotely from home to office? 
What other option do we have instead of using VPN?
please give me some hints.
Thanks

Comment: Question about home networking, and questions from end-users of corporate networks, are both specifically off-topic for this forum. Please see the Help Center for which types of questions are allowed, and which types are not allowed. You need to take this up the the network staff of your company.

Comment: VPN, tunnel (encrypted or not), direct point-to-point link.

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. As currently stated your question is too broad to be answered. Either it has too many possible answers or a good answer would be too long for this format. Please [edit] your question and it will automatically start a reopen vote. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful to improve your question. It is also bordering on a product recommendation/poll question which is also off topic.

Answer (score 1):

If you want plain transparent network integration, VPN is indeed the way to go.  If you're happy with just taking over the screen of your office computer, there are other options:

1. If you have access to your office's router and are allowed to do some portforwarding, you can look at installing a VNC server to your work desktop.  VNC servers are available for any flavour of OS.  Some implementations are commercial ([RealVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/)) but there are also Open Source and therefore version free to use ([TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/)).
2. If your computer happens to be a Mac, there's [Apple Remote Desktop](http://www.apple.com/remotedesktop/) which uses similar VNC technology, but more secure.  The server version is not free though - about $80.  Needs portforwarding also.
3. Another option that doesn't require router portforwarding is [Teamviewer](http://www.teamviewer.com), available for PC, mac and some linux flavours.  You can use the free version as long as you don't make money out of it.
4. If you're using Chrome as your desktop browser, there is CRD - [Chrome Remote Desktop](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chrome-remote-desktop/gbchcmhmhahfdphkhkmpfmihenigjmpp?hl=en).  Free and no need for portforwarding.

Comment: all of the 'other options' are still available when using a VPN. I would encourage to always use a VPN tunnel to ensure the connections are secure and not open for anyone trying to connect to a port. Other than that, nice options :)